# Filter skyscrapers higher than 500 meters in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I try to construct a SPARQL query, where I get a list of skyscrapers with a height of more then 500 meters.

I realized, that the property height (P2048) is measured in different units (meter, foot, centimeter). This would not be a problem for me to calculate the different units into meters.

But my problem is to figure out, that unit is used for the property height.

So my question: how can I get the unit for the property height?

My query so far, where `?unit` is just empty:

```
SELECT ?skyscraper ?skyscraperLabel ?height ?unit WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?skyscraper wdt:P31 wd:Q11303.
  ?skyscraper wdt:P2048 ?height.
  FILTER(?height > 500)
  OPTIONAL { ?skyscraper wdt:P2876 ?unit. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fskyscraper%20%3FskyscraperLabel%20%3Fheight%20%3Funit%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11303.%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP2048%20%3Fheight.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fheight%20%3E%20500%29%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP2876%20%3Funit.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100)

Comment: Use `?skyscraper p:P2048/psn:P2048/wikibase:quantityAmount ?height.` to get the normalized height in meters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but I do not understand :-) Do you know by chance any reference, where I could learn/understand how this property works ?

Comment: @mcflysoft, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Normalized_values (but unfortunately, `wdtn:` works for normalized external IDs only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the unit itelf use `:P2048/psv:P2048/wikibase:quantityUnit`:

```
SELECT ?skyscraper ?skyscraperLabel ?height ?unit ?unitLabel WHERE {
  ?skyscraper wdt:P31 wd:Q11303.
  ?skyscraper p:P2048/psv:P2048 ?vn.
  ?vn wikibase:quantityAmount ?height.
  ?vn wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fskyscraper%20%3FskyscraperLabel%20%3Fheight%20%3Funit%20%3FunitLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11303.%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20p%3AP2048%2Fpsv%3AP2048%20%3Fvn.%0A%20%20%3Fvn%20wikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Fheight.%0A%20%20%3Fvn%20wikibase%3AquantityUnit%20%3Funit.%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100%0A)

However, following AKSW and Stanislav Kralin's comments above, it is better to use [Normalized values](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Normalized_values) using the `psn:` prefix: `p:P2048/psn:P2048/wikibase:quantityAmount`:

```
SELECT ?skyscraper ?skyscraperLabel ?height WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?skyscraper wdt:P31 wd:Q11303.
  ?skyscraper p:P2048/psn:P2048/wikibase:quantityAmount ?height.
  FILTER(?height >= 500)
}
ORDER BY DESC(?height)
LIMIT 1000
```

[Try this here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fskyscraper%20%3FskyscraperLabel%20%3Fheight%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11303.%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20p%3AP2048%2Fpsn%3AP2048%2Fwikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Fheight.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fheight%20%3E%3D%20500%29%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fheight%29%0ALIMIT%201000%0A%0A%0A)

Since some buildings contains multiple height values (for example, [One World Trade Center](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11245) have both [architectural height (Q24192182)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q24192182) and [height to pinnacle (Q26970842)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q26970842) values), some aggregation is needed to retrieve one value per building in SPARQL:

```
SELECT ?skyscraper ?skyscraperLabel (MAX(?h) AS ?height) WHERE {
  ?skyscraper wdt:P31 wd:Q11303.
  ?skyscraper p:P2048/psn:P2048/wikibase:quantityAmount ?h.
  FILTER(?h >= 500)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?skyscraper ?skyscraperLabel
ORDER BY DESC(?height)
LIMIT 1000
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fskyscraper%20%3FskyscraperLabel%20%28MAX%28%3Fh%29%20AS%20%3Fheight%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11303.%0A%20%20%3Fskyscraper%20p%3AP2048%2Fpsn%3AP2048%2Fwikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Fh.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fh%20%3E%3D%20500%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fskyscraper%20%3FskyscraperLabel%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fheight%29%0ALIMIT%201000)