# timeout for sparql query. Is there another way to query sparql for my case?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to get all mountains greater then 8000 meters. For this I [query the Wikidata RDF database](https://query.wikidata.org/).

Because the unit of the property elevation of the class "mountain" can be feet or meters, I need to figure out what unit is the elevation. For this I started with the following query, which leads always into a timeout! Is there another more performant way to query or join RDF information?

My query so far, which maybe is the wrong approach.

```
SELECT ?Berg ?BergLabel ?elevation ?unit 
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Berg wdt:P31 wd:Q8502.
  OPTIONAL { ?Berg wdt:P2044 ?elevation. }
  OPTIONAL { ?elevation wdt:P2302 ?unit.}
  FILTER (?elevation > 8800)
#FILTER (?unit = 'meter')
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522596/filter-skyscrapers-higher-than-500-meters-in-wikidata) from StanislavKralin in the question that you deleted. Why do you ignore this link, it basically contains the answer and how to handle normalized units.

Comment: And don't use OPTIONALs, it's not necessary

Comment: `SELECT ?Berg ?BergLabel ?height WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Berg wdt:P31 wd:Q8502.
  ?Berg p:P2044/psn:P2044/wikibase:quantityAmount ?height.
  FILTER(?height >= 8000)
}
ORDER BY DESC(?height)
LIMIT 1000`

Comment: Thanks you very much. I'll try to understand the "quantityAmount". It helped me lot. Thanks.

Comment: `OPTIONAL { ?elevation wdt:P2302 ?unit.} but if ?elevation is a number (a literal), it can't be the subject.